# JPA: Unidirectional one-to-many relationship with composite semi-shared primary key without join table

Tags: jpa, composite-primary-key, join

JPA:

How can I model the following in JPA:

- a **uni-directional one-to-many** relationship
- where the **owning entity has a single-column** application-determined **primary key** AND
- where the **child entity** has a **composite primary** key AND
- where one part of the **child's primary key is the parent's primary key** AND
- *avoiding* JPA generating a join table.

Any ideas?

Comment: You would only get a join table if you didnt specify any `@JoinColumn`, so just make sure you have a `@JoinColumn`. The rest of it is independent of that

Comment: I have an idea: could you present us an example set of entities (even sketch or so)? I am interested especially of the case of _where the owning entity has a single-column application-determined primary key AND where the child entity has a composite primary key_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out myself how to do this.

- You need to annotate the foreign key in the owning entity with

  ```
  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinColumn(name = "myId", referencedColumnName = "parentId")
  private List<ChildEntity> childEntity;
  ```
- The primary key part in the child entity that is also the foreign key referencing the owning entity must not be annotated as being a foreign key, so e.g.:

  ```
  @Id
  private String parentId;
  ```
- The usual rules concerning composite primary keys apply for the child class (primary key class annotated with `@Embeddable` etc.)
- As user DN1 commented, the `@JoinColumn` annotation must be used, but it must be specified at the foreign reference in the owning class.
- For some reason, you also must not use `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn` instead of `@JoinColumn`, otherwise JPA **will** generate join tables.

Another challenge would be that the owning class's primary is also composite, but I haven't tried that.